# Kaminari not respecting .per() setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari

```
@items = @cats + @dogs + @birds
@pag_items = Kaminari.paginate_array(@items).page(params[:page]).per(9)

puts @pag_items.count
6
```

The @items array has 23 items.
Why is the @pag_items array only holding 6 items?

If i set it to 5, or 4 it will hold that many. But more than 6 it won't.

Thanks!

Comment: you are doing a `puts @items.count` is that a typo?

Comment: what is `params[:page]`? If it equals 3, you'll get 6 last elements.

Comment: params[:page] is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably has `max_per_page` setting enabled:

```
Kaminari.configure { |s| s.max_per_page = 6 }
@items = (1..23).to_a
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23] 
@pag_items = Kaminari.paginate_array(@items).page(1).per(9)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't remember setting up an initializer for kaminari, but I had one setup, and hadn't noticed it. It was in fact setting `max_per_page = 6`.